# Anyone have a flowchart for determining what document mode IE10 will use, like this one for IE9?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-10

I found this completely wonderful document that shows the information I want, but for IE9.  This helped clear up a lot of confusion I had about how IE document modes work:

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2010/Jun/16_IEsCompatibilityFeaturesforSiteDevelopers_1.svg

I've searched for an updated version for IE10 but haven't found anything.  Anyone seen the equivalent but updated?

My experience so far with msdn's documentation such as their [Defining document compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has been very frustrating, with a lot of going in circles and undefined terms.

Particularly, the question I've been unable to answer (though really I'm only looking for the answer still because I'm frustrated that it's not provided anywhere) is this:  Does IE10 Compatibility Mode still mean it's emulating IE7?  I guess I assume that it does, but it annoys me immensely that nothing seems to say so explicitly.  Mad props to anyone who can find someplace that the MSDN documents say whether it does or not.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but it came up as a top hit when I was looking for an IE 11 update to this chart. The following page was moderately helpful: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ua/browsers/ie/document-modes.html

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for an updated diagram, and found the following after doing a Google image search (scroll to bottom):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx

There are links on the left to take you to the compatibility view settings and doctype table, as they're not included in the flow chart on the page.

For your second question, about whether Compatibility Mode is still emulating IE7, I assume you mean that you get to IE10 Compatibility Mode by clicking the icon in the browser and not by setting a meta tag or header.  I believe the answer is yes, but not because I have seen it in Microsoft's documentation.  When I click that icon and look in Developer Tools, I see that the Browser Mode is "IE10 Compatibility" and the Document Mode is "IE7 Standards" so it seems like that's the default.  You can see this happen on nytimes.com.